# I am trying to get my vb program to read from a file

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

I am trying to get my program to read from a file on visual basic but it keeps saying the file does not exist, I have tried different file paths and other things but i cant seem to get it working.

my code is :

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Public Class MOTform
    Dim custfile As StreamReader
    Dim strCustArray() As String
    Dim strCustDetails As String




Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    radMOTYes.Checked = True
    If File.Exists("cust_db.txt") Then
        ' Open the file.
        custfile = File.OpenText("cust_db.txt")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("cust_db.txt" & " does not exist.")

    End If
    strCustDetails = custfile.ReadLine()
    strCustArray = Split(strCustDetails, ",")
    Me.Text = strCustDetails
    custfile.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you run this code inside Visual Studio? Remember that in debug the current folder is under the project root BIN\DEBUG (or x86 variant) folder

Comment: You should point `. Fileexists` to the fully qualified path to make sure it you're looking in the correct folder.

Comment: Yeah thanks that works is there anyway you can have the file outside this folder ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not DebugMyCodeForMe.Com.

Answer (score 0):

go to the file you want to read from, right click on it, click Properties, copy the path from Location and insert it to the code

Comment: it will work even if the file is outside the folder, however you will have to change the path in the code to the new one

Comment: I have to send it to my lecturer so would the file path not be different then on his laptop ?

Comment: well, your professor will not be able to read it from the file because that file probably does not exist on his computer. I guess your lecturer will just check your code without running it because he should know that he does not have the file you are referencing. also make sure to rate my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects the file in the same folder where your program runs because you don't have any kind of path. This is fine when you deploy your final executable because there is no BIN\DEBUG there.
In debug inside VS instead you need to have that file in that folder for the same reason. Your debugged exe runs in that folder. You can add the txt file to your project and change the property [Copy to Output Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx) to Copy Always.

However, keeping a data file in the same folder where your program runs is not a good practice, in particular if the file is not read only.
The operating system can prevent your application to change that file if you deploy your application in some kind of reserved folder (like C:\program files).

I suggest to use the config file adding an AppSettings key to specify the folder where you keep the file and then reading that key at runtime to build your path

For example

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DataFolder" value="C:\programdata\myappdatafolder"/>
</appSettings>
```

and then

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    radMOTYes.Checked = True
    Dim fullFileName = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataFolder"), "cust_db.txt")
    If File.Exists(fullFileName) Then
        ' Open the file.
        custfile = File.OpenText(fullFileName)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(fullFileName & " does not exist.")

    End If
```

In this way you can change the configuration file to have your file where is most convenient for your scenario